# Is it possible to run devenv.exe in foreground?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, build-process, devenv

I need to build a solution with CAB Project.
As far as I understand I should use devenv.exe in order to build CAB.
Following command line starts ***devenv.exe*** in background:
**devenv.exe MyActiveX.sln /Rebuild "Release"**

Is it possible to run devenv.exe in foreground?
I would like to get build traces not in file but to stdout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to run `devenv.com` in this case which is the *console* application<sup>1</sup>. `devenv.exe` is a GUI application and therefore simply can't print anything to your current console.

---

<sup>1</sup> As `dumpbin` will tell you.

Comment: `dumpbin` is a small utility which will simply dump the PE metadata. This isn't related to .NET in any way and just a part of how Windows works. An application belongs to *one* subsystem, which, for Windows applications, may mean console or GUI. a console application can create a window as well but it will always have the console attached to it while a GUI application can create a console but can't re-use the one it was started from. The usage of `.com`  and `.exe` as the respective extensions simply ensures that when run from  `cmd` the console application will be called (due to `PATHEXT`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run "devenv.com"